# Mixed model random-effect structure for repeated measures, split plot design in R (nlme or lme4)

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I am seeking advice on structuring the random-effects component of a mixed model in R. The data that I am modeling come from an ecological experiment with a repeatedly-measured split-plot design. At each of 5 sites (**site = A, B, C, D, E**) experimenters set up 2 treatments (**x = treatment, control**) in separate plots. A response variable (**y**) was measured every quarter (**quarter = Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4**) through time for 8 years (**year = 1–8**). There is no replication of treatments within sites (thus each site contains 1 treatment plot and 1 control plot). Hence this is a split-plot design (**site / treatment**) with repeated measures.

Some fake data:

```
dat <- expand.grid('year' = 2001:2008, 
               'quarter' = paste("Q", 1:4, sep = ""), 
               'site' = LETTERS[1:5], 
               'treatment' = c('control', 'manipulate'))

dat$yr.qt = dat$year + as.numeric(ifelse(dat$quarter == "Q1", 0.125 + 0,
                                    ifelse(dat$quarter == "Q2", 0.125 + 0.25,  
                                         ifelse(dat$quarter == "Q3", 0.125 + 0.5,
                                                  0.125 + 0.75))))

dat$time.step <- ((dat$yr.qt - min(dat$yr.qt)) / 0.25) + 1

dat$y <- sample(seq(0, 10, by = 0.01), size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)

# Structure of the data
xtabs(~ site + time.step, data = dat)
```

The focal question is, *"What is the effect of the treatment on the response?"*. A secondary question is, *"Does the treatment effect change over time?"*

Assume for the moment that sites were selected randomly from a range of potential sites and that the experiments are not concerned with site-specific trends. Also assume that we only want to control for seasonality ('quarter') as a covariate.

After reading Pinheiro and Bates (2000) and Zuur et al. (2009), I have come to two potential ways to structure the random effects of a mixed model using *nlme* (I have preferred using *nlme* over *lme4* for the moment so that I can explore structuring the variance to deal with heterogeneity or serial autocorrelation). These models are:

```
library('nlme')

mod1 <- lme(y ~ treatment + quarter + time.step + treatment:time.step,
            random = ~ 1 | site,
            data = dat)

mod2 <- lme(y ~ treatment + quarter + time.step + treatment:time.step,
            random = ~ 1 | site/treatment,
            data = dat)
```

Considering that I have no replication of treatments within sites, which is the more appropriate model structure? Examination of the ANOVA tables for 'mod1' vs. 'mod2' shows 309 vs. 4 denominator degrees of freedom, respectively. Is 'mod1' pseudo-replicating the data? Or, is 'mod2' overdetermined?

Many thanks for your feedback!